# Warning: This Message Contains Blocked Content

Tags: wordpress, facebook

when I am trying to my post on facebook showing this error how to solve this error
please guide me I am attaching a screenshot

[image]

Comment: It seems the content you try to share is simply blocked by Facebook.

Comment: how to unblock could you guide me steps

Comment: Try using the Debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ if you think the content is legit.

Comment: you did appeal already? then there is nothing else you can do. btw, this is off topic on stackoverflow, it´s a platform for questions related to programming only. we cannot help you with something only facebook can change.